# Matplotlib: plot_surface doesnt show right colors, colormap as 4th dimension

Tags: python, matlab, 3d, surface, colormap

I am new to programming
I tried to plot the same 3 dimensional graph twice, once in Matlab, once in python.
Wanted to add a fourth dimension for colormap.
Turns out, it´s pretty easy in matlab to do so, but in python it seems not to be working as expected.[Matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAGoW.png)
[Matlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3b9U.png)

As you can see, the colors differ a lot and that`s not just because of the choice of colors. The hole structure is kind of messed up... to me, it seems like some colored areas are overlapping each other.

already tried it with facecolors, but cmap got me closest to what i am looking for

would highly appreciate some help, to get a clearer Result.

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap, ListedColormap




x = np.asmatrix(rot_el)       (all 120x90 arrays)
y = np.asmatrix(rot_mech)
z = np.asmatrix(torque)
z = z[0:119,:]

I_eff = np.asmatrix(I_eff) (4th-dim)

minn, maxx = I_eff.min(), I_eff.max()

#I_eff goes from 0 - 100

vals = [0, 50, 100]
colors=["yellow", "green", "yellow"]
norm = plt.Normalize(minn, maxx)
tuples = list(zip(map(norm, vals), colors))
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", tuples)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(221,projection = '3d')


'''worked but wrong colormapping
colormap = cm.get_cmap('viridis')
colors = colormap(I_eff_normalized)
sm = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap = colormap)
sm.set_clim(minn, maxx)
'''

'''facecolors
norm = plt.Normalize(minn,maxx)
m = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm = norm, cmap = 'summer')
m.set_array([])
fcolors = m.to_rgba(I_eff)
#cmap1 = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', [(0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1)])
#c = mpl.colors.Normalize(minn, maxx)'''.

#CART.

surf = ax.plot_surface(x,y,z, rcount = 120, ccount = 90, cmap = cmap, alpha = 1, antialiased = True)
inv = plt.gca()
#inv.invert_xaxis()
plt.xlabel(r'$rot_{ el} [°]$')
plt.ylabel(r'$rot_{ mech}[°]$')
ax.set_zlabel("torque [Nm]")
ax.title.set_text('cart.')
plt.colorbar(surf, label = r'$I_{ eff}$', anchor = (1.0, 0.5))

#POLAR

rot_el_p = (rot_el) * (2*np.pi)/360
rot_mech_p = (rot_mech) * (2*np.pi)/360
X = np.cos(rot_el_p) * z
Y = np.sin(rot_el_p) * z
Z = np.sin(rot_mech_p) * z
bx = fig.add_subplot(222,projection = '3d')
bsurf = bx.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, cmap = cmap, alpha = 1, antialiased = True)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('z')
bx.set_zlabel('z')
bx.title.set_text('polar')




plt.show()
```